# Finding repeating patterns in a sentence using reqular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to find repeating patterns in the following sentence using reqular expressions in java:

`username|s:5:"derick256";privilege|s:5:"derick542";premium|s:5:"derik542";`

I need to extract the following, and potentially more, so I need a solution that is easily expandable...

1. username `derick256`
2. privilege `derick 542`
3. premium `derik542`

This is my code...

```
String re1="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))"; // Variable Name 1
String re2=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re3="(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)";   // Uninteresting: var
String re4=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re5="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))"; // Variable Name 2

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
if (m.find()){
    String word1=m.group(1);
    String word2=m.group(2);
    System.out.print("("+word1.toString()+")"+"("+word2.toString()+")"+"\n");
}
```

But I only got `username derick256`. Could anyone please assist me to understand the error.

Comment: Is the absence of the character `'c'` intentional in `"derik542"`?

Comment: yes..i meant it can be any other word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `if(m.find())` to `while(m.find())`.